# Creating PostGIS my first Table

Tags: postgresql, geospatial, postgis

I have about 2 million records in a table in PostgreSQL database with columns such as "source_location", "destination_location", "source_lat","source_long","destination_lat","destination_long" etc.

How do I make use of this table to convert it into Spatial table in PostGIS so that I can fire spatial queries on this data?

Comment: Definitely need more info here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that your data is in the table `foo`. First add geometry columns:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('foo', 'source_geom', 4326, 'POINT', 2);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('foo', 'destination_geom', 4326, 'POINT', 2);
```

Than you can set values of geometry columns:

```
UPDATE foo SET
  source_geom =
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(source_lon, source_lat), 4326),
  destination_geom = 
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(destination_lon, destination_lat), 4326);
```

As a result you can use columns `source_geom` and `destination_geom` in spatial queries:

```
SELECT * FROM foo
WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(source_geom, destination_geom) > 1000000;
```

This query returns all records where distance between source and destination > 1000 kilometers.

Comment: Thank you Aleksandr Dezhin! but as I tried to follow your steps, I got the following error:

function addgeometrycolumn("unknown", "unknown", integer, "unknown", integer) does not exist

What should be done in this case?

Comment: The above error was resolved by installing the 'postgis' and 'postgis_topology' extensions for my database. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Aleksandr Dezhin, as per your suggestion, I added the two geometry columns and set the SRID to them. However, when I tried executing the above mentioned spatial query, I got the following error: ERROR: Coordinate values are out of range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY type (SQL state: 22023).   What could be the reason?

Comment: @KetanBarshikar did you use the axis order (longitude, latitude)? If so, do the values fit in that range?

Comment: @KetanBarshikar, you can find points with coordinates out of range using simple query like this: `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE source_lon < -180 OR source_lon > 180 OR destination_lon < -180 OR destination_lon > 180 OR source_lat < -90 OR source_lat > 90 OR destination_lat < -90 OR destination_lat > 90`

Answer (score 1):

The error:

```
function addgeometrycolumn("unknown", "unknown", integer, "unknown", integer) does not exist
```

tells you that PostgreSQL cannot recognise this PostGIS function.

This could be because:

1. PostGIS is not installed (see http://postgis.refractions.net/download/);
2. Your database does not have these functions loaded (see http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiNewbieAddgeometrycolumn)

Answer (score 0):

[Creating a spatial table - PostGIS manual](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.3/ch04.html#id2571655)

It suggests that you use AddGeometryColumn.